# Mysql: When should I declare Column of type CHAR(String) to use UTF8 or Latin1?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, flask-sqlalchemy, iso-8859-1, utf8mb4

Since Mysql>=8.0 has supported collation in UTF8MB4.

But If the Column of type CHAR is an alphanumeric string, would it be better to custom collation in UTF8 or latin1 ?

---

I use `Flask-Sqlalchemy`, and my project sets `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+mysqldb://root:@localhost:3306/testdb?charset=utf8mb4'`

But After upgrade mysql to 8.0 , all tables are created with collation of UTF8MB4 .

eg:

```py
class Topic(db.Model, CoModel):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(168))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
```

==> mysql

```sql
CREATE TABLE `topic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(168) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Should I custom `name = db.Column(db.String(168, collation="utf8_general_ci"))`

---

UTF8MB4 is good at support huge number of character encoding.

Should I configure utf8mb4 by default and use it everywhere ?

Comment: If you use a lot, and I mean **a lot** of non-ASCII Latin-1 characters (i.e. "ä", "ü" etc.), but don't need any non-Latin1 characters, then you get some storage savings by using Latin1 vs. UTF-8. But that needs to be a pretty substantial amount to make any practical difference.

Comment: You are right.  Now I need to alter table collation from utf8mb4 to utf8,  then it raise a new question to me: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514911/why-tables-index-storage-size-is-bigger-after-change-charset-from-utf8mb4-to-ut

Comment: @NicoNing - I puked all over the accepted answer to that other Question.  Bottom line for this Question:  do _not_ change to utf8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going forward, you should use utf8mb4 for almost all CHAR/VARCHAR/TEXT columns.

`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` covers essentially all the world's character sets.  If your client encodes characters as `UTF-8` (the outside equivalent of utf8mb4), then utf8mb4 is good.

Moving from `utf8` to `utf8mb4` is good.  The former is a subset of the latter.  The difference is Emoji and some Chinese.

Mixing `latin1` with `utf8` or `utf8mb4`, is possible, but this forum is full of programmers/dbas who screw it up.

8.0 changed the default to utf8mb4 for a lot of good reasons.

Note MySQL's convention of xxxx_yyy_ci being a *collation* that applies to the *character set* xxxx.  That is utf8_general_ci belongs with utf8, *not* utf8mb4.

A "character set" is an encoding.  A collation is a set of rules for comparing strings.  Example:  Should `'A'` be treated as equal to `'a'`.

Comment: Your answers are right for most situation.

But if data size is very  huge and comfirmed only alphanumeric string ,  utf-8 or lantin1 is better.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58514911/why-tables-index-storage-size-is-bigger-after-change-charset-from-utf8mb4-to-utf8

Comment: @NicoNing - deceze makes a valid argument for latin1 (with caveats).  But that does _not_ apply to utf8.  All utf8 characters are encoded identically in utf8mb4, hence the same space requirement.