# Why table's index storage size is bigger after change charset from utf8mb4 to utf8?

Tags: mysql, performance, character-encoding

Executed: `alter table device_msg convert to character set 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci';"`

As my expect，table data size change to smaller.

But at the same time, table index size change to bigger ?

What happen and why ?

ps: table data size and index size are calculated by information_schema.TABLES

---

DbEngine:   InnoDB

Table Before:

```
CREATE TABLE `device_msg` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sn` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `msg` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `device_UNIQUE` (`sn`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62077733 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Table After:

```
CREATE TABLE `device_msg` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sn` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `msg` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `device_UNIQUE` (`sn`,`time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62077733 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Before:

```
totalSize: 2.14 GB
indexSize: 282.98 MB
dataSize: 1.86 GB
avg_row_len:  297B
```

After

```
totalSize: 1.93 GB
indexSize: 413.97 MB
dataSize: 1.52 GB
avg_row_len:  260B
```

If data of information_schema.TABLES is not accurate,

How to make it right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in my opinion

As I read on MySQL document about the limitation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

> By default, the index key prefix length limit is 767 bytes

if the index column exceeds this size, it will be truncated.
I assume your indexed column value has 255 characters.

in the case of utf8mb4, 1 character = 4 bytes, the limit is around 191 characters. 
So 191 characters will be added to index, other (255-191=64) characters will be truncated from the index.

When you change encoding to utf8 (at that time 1 character = 3 bytes), the indexed limit will become around 255 characters.
It means your column value, all 255 characters, will be added to index without truncating.

The characters that are added to the index increased from 191 characters to 255 characters, so the index size was also increased.

Comment: The length of  indexed column value is less than 48
primary key is  integer
unique key `device_UNIQUE` is `$sn_$timestamp`  (24+1+13)

Comment: Did you use this query to get the index_length and compare with the number above?
show table status from [db_name]

Comment: I just run `show table status` as you said.
The output result is ` Index_length = 296730624` ,  ~  282.98MB  


Then I go back to check information_schema.TABLES.
And then I found the data was changed  to the same as result of show status.


?????


I used to run `optimize table`  before read your answer.

   . Which query do affect the  `information_schema.TABLES` ?

Comment: yes, I also tested on my own data, and it seems the index size doesn't change. I'm not sure is there any cases the information_schema.TABLES slowly on updating data? I'll also research more.

Comment: It's very strange ,  slow is ok, change is ok, but why bigger so much ? I still have many big tables require to be changed from utf8mb4 to utf8.  I will try to handle this question. Thank you very much.

Comment: 255 and 767 are not relevant to the Question.  Exceeding the size will _not_ truncate (other things happen).  1 utf8 char is _up to_ 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

- The space taken by utf8mb4, then utf8 (assuming there were no 4-byte characters beforehand) is the same, *in spite of the numbers you show*.
- This `ALTER` required rebuilding the table and the indexes.
- InnoDB structures the data and each secondary index in a BTrees.
- Depending on the order by which you insert elements into a BTree, more or fewer "block splits" will occur.

So, You can't really say whether it is the character set change or the rebuild that lead to the index getting bigger and the data getting smaller.

I say it was *not* the charset change.